# How to enable zoom controls and pinch zoom in a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

The default Browser app for Android shows zoom controls when you're scrolling and also allows for pinch zooming. How can I enable this feature for my own Webview?

I've tried:

```
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

but neither of the features get enabled as a result. Btw I've set a `WebChromeClient` and a `WebViewClient` for the Webview if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Strange. Inside OnCreate method, I'm using

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

And it's working fine here.
Anything particular in your webview ?

Comment: While this will allow pinch-to-zoom, it will also display a zoom overlay control (Galaxy S3). In order to disable the on-screen zoom tool, but retain the pinch-to-zoom functionality, you need to call webView.setDisplayZoomControls(false) as well.

Comment: ^ `webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);`

Comment: All of these don't work for me. Try this website for example: "https://www.nbc26.com/robocalls/battling-robocalls-breaking-down-relentless-and-annoying-calls"  . It doesn't let me zoom. Does it really work for you? please show entire code for it.

Comment: If anyone is looking at this answer and wondering where the webview object comes from, you can get it via `WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();` as shown in [this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36464728/7407567)

Comment: If you use Xamarin.Android web view renderer then it's code as below

Control.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
Control.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
Control.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;

Answer (score 120):

Use these:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: plus 1, for the answer.. helped me.

Comment: Yes, setBuiltInZoomControls(true) and setDisplayZoomControls(false) worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

Check if you don't have a **ScrollView wrapping your Webview**.

In my case that was the problem. It seems ScrollView gets in the way of the pinch gesture.

To fix it, just **take your Webview outside the ScrollView**.

Comment: Works great for me. Now I can delete my nested scroll view altogether!

Comment: it work when you can add android:fillViewport= true

      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
       >

Answer (score 16):

Inside OnCreate, add:

```
 webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
 webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Inside the html document, add:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=yes">
</head>
</html>
```

Inside javascript, omit:

```
//event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```

Comment: The default boolean for setSupportZoom is `true`, therefor no need for `webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);` by default.

Comment: good answer!  you mentioned the HTML related issues, this is the key solving my problem! thank you !

Answer (score 11):

To enable zoom controls in a WebView, add the following line:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

With this line of code, you get the zoom enabled in your WebView, if you want to remove the zoom in and zoom out buttons provided, add the following line of code:

```
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code, I get working fine.

```
 webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
 webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```