# Cordova : How to enable viewport zoom

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

I'm currently trying to enable native viewport zoom (like the native web zoom I mean) on Cordova Android (webview).

Here's my viewport tag :

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

And I tried something like this :

```
         function onDeviceReady() {


                ImgCache.options.chromeQuota = 50*1024*1024;

                var domElement = document.getElementById('main-html');
                angular.bootstrap(domElement, "myApp");

                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // this line

            }
```

As said there : [How to enable zoom controls and pinch zoom in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121053/how-to-enable-zoom-controls-and-pinch-zoom-in-a-webview)

But it doesn't work. What I am missing ?

Comment: do you want to zoom particular area or all app ???

Comment: try to place in meta tag width=100%, height=100% and try it ...i think i will zoom....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

put following in your index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

put following in the onCreate method of your main Android Java File inside src/com/packagename directory:

```
super.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
super.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM); 
super.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

also add following packages in your main java file:

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings; 
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Sure it helps ! Thank you ! Note that : 'super.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);' made an error on compilation, so I commented it.

Comment: Great. Sorry about the error. Updated the answer with missing packages. there should not be any errors now :)

Comment: Anyone seeing this in 2019 on may need to use a webview object instead of `super.appView` which you can get using `WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();` as shown in [this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36464728/7407567)