# how to enable webview zoom behind linear layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, touch

I have made an app in which there is a transparent image on the webview.
My webview has zoom functionality enabled, but after I put transparent image in a transparent `LinearLayout` on the `Webview`, I cannot get zoom enabled. Perhaps the transparent `LinearLayout`   (containing partial transparent image)   on the `Webview` restricts the touch event to be detected on `Webview`. 
So how do I solve this ?
My application screenshot looks like the image given below.

[image]

webview.xml file:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/WebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom|center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

search_image.xml file:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/overlayLayout"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_search"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your layout files here..!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to enable zoom controls and pinch zoom in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121053/how-to-enable-zoom-controls-and-pinch-zoom-in-a-webview)

> Check if you don't have a `ScrollView` wrapping your `Webview`.
>
> In my case that was the problem. It seems `ScrollView` gets in the way
>   of the pinch gesture.
>
> To fix it, just take your `WebView` outside the `ScrollView`.

then in your `onCreate` method use:

```
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

And it should working fine here.