# Webview android cannot zoom

Tags: java, android

Now I create web view in my android. My webview is retrieved from available url. But now my webview cannot zoom in and out. Hope can understand my question and help me. Thank You
Below is my code:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
WebView webView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    return view;

}


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable zoom controls and pinch zoom in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121053/how-to-enable-zoom-controls-and-pinch-zoom-in-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

On API >= 11, you can use:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

As per the SDK:

```
public void setDisplayZoomControls (boolean enabled)
```

Also make sure that another controlling factor is "user-scalable" in the meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```